# Sorting in excel when a column has a word and number

Tags: xml, excel, sorting

I have converted my xml to excel as the following:

[image]

As you can see my `guide/_text` column is alphanumeric.I want to sort it only based on the numeric.How do I do that?

Note: I cannot separate numbers and word since I'll convert it back to xml and I need it as alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use advanced sorting techniques. Follow the following steps:

1) First create a formula next to your guide/_text column, into a blank cell as `=TEXT("###",G2)`.

2) Next, drag the handle that will appear onto the first data cell of `guide/_text` all the way down.

3) Then sort the data by new column. Select the helper column you created and then click Data > Sort, then in the dialog box, select `Expand the selection`.

4)Then click `sort` to open sort dialog, under column, choose the `guide/_text` column that you want to sort and then sort it as you want to sort :).

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to have the Numbers separated by Text to columns and then use the Numeric column for sorting data.

Comment: I need it as it is.I will convert it back to xml after sorting.

Comment: Then you can add another column for concatenation and then delete the parsed columns. Will that work fine for you??